# Мультиплатформенное приложение на С#

Tags: c#, windows, mysql, сокет, linux

Собственно стоит задача написания мультиплатформенного приложение на С#.

Нужно чтобы ставилось как процесс в linux / windows, или возможно консольное приложение. Основная задача работа с сокетом и MySQL.

Знаю что подобное есть в Delphi IDE (современный паскаль, lazarus вроде)

В какую сторону смотреть? Какой IDE этим занимается?

Comment: Первый же [клик в гугляндекс][1], однако.


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono

Comment: @klopp Вопрос был про IDE. Mono вроде не подходит

Comment: В Xamarin IDE прямым текстом не указывается, что один и тот же проект можно собирать и дебажить под разные платформы.

Comment: И MonoDevelop не подходит? Если честно, я не настолько глубоко вникал, по мне так qt, например, вполне кроссплатформнное решение, если речь о компилируемых языках :) Но уверен, что будет интерес - найду информацию куда быстрей, чем ждать ответа часами...

Comment: а qt - какой язык разработки?

Comment: Базовый язык - [C++][1] (ссылки на всё остальное - там же)


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt

Answer (score 1):

IDE MonoDevelop, причём как под Linux так и под Windows.